# How to identify String verities over known categories by Scripting dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a table that I need to add a restrict role to highlight the rows that contain a specific string type and release any rows that return with string verities.

the roles that I want to achieve are:

- If all the rows under the same customer number are provisioned as "Bad" then this is OK.
- If all the rows under the same customer number are mixed between "RR" & "Bad" then this is ok.
- If all the rows under the same customer number are provisioned as "RR" then highlight these rows.

**with excluding the rows that have Category "XO" and provisioned as "Exc" from the role**

My table :

| Customer Number | Customer Name | Invoice | Provision | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55850 | ABC | 124587 | Exc | XX |
| 55850 | ABC | 124588 | RR | XX |
| 55850 | ABC | 124589 | RR | XX |
| 55850 | ABC | 124590 | RR | XX |
| 55850 | ABC | 124591 | RR | XX |
| 32336 | DEF | 124592 | Bad | XO |
| 32336 | DEF | 124593 | Bad | XO |
| 30131 | GHI | 124594 | Exc | XX |
| 30131 | GHI | 124595 | RR | XX |
| 30131 | GHI | 124596 | RR | XX |
| 13914 | JKL | 124597 | Exc | XX |
| 13914 | JKL | 124598 | RR | XX |
| 13914 | JKL | 124599 | Bad | XX |
| 13914 | JKL | 124600 | RR | XX |

The code I have so far highlights if the rows provisioned as "RR" (which is needed) but still doesn't ignore the customer number that has a "Bad" row among the "RR" rows.
your help is much appreciated and Please let me know if you need more clarification.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim z, y, rg, urg As Range
Dim r As Long, ar
Dim x As Variant: x = RGB(200, 205, 5)
Dim colDx, colTx, colvM As String
With ActiveSheet
   Dim tb As ListObject: Set tb = .ListObjects(1)
   Set z = tb.ListColumns("Customer Number").DataBodyRange
   Set y = tb.ListColumns("Category").DataBodyRange
  Set rg = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range(z, y))
                ar = rg.Value
                 End With
 For r = 1 To UBound(ar) 'loop in the tb
    colDx = Trim(ar(r, tb.ListColumns("Provision").Index)) 'column provision
    colTx = Trim(ar(r, tb.ListColumns("Category").Index)) 'column category
    If UCase(colDx) <> "EXC" Then 'if not provision is Exc
    If UCase(colTx) = "XX" Then 'if the category is XX
    colDx = Trim(ar(r, tb.ListColumns("Provision").Index))
    colvM = Trim(ar(r, tb.ListColumns("Customer Number").Index))
       If dict.Exists(colvM) Then
           'if what stored in dict and the new value matching
              If StrComp(colDx, dict(colvM), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               If urg Is Nothing Then
                 Set urg = rg.Rows(r)
                         Else
                            Set urg = Union(urg, rg.Rows(r))
                          End If 'Urg
                      End If 'Strcomp
                    Else
                       dict.Add colvM, colDx ' add the customer number and the provision
                  End If 'dict exists
          End If 'XX
    End If 'EXC
 Next r
 If Not urg Is Nothing Then
 rg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
 urg.Interior.Color = x
 End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use two `Dictionary` objects to track the `Provision` of customers

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm132112)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim oDicBAD As Object, oDicRR As Object
    Dim i As Long, sKey As Variant, ColCnt As Long
    Dim arrData, oTab As ListObject, rngHL As Range, rngData As Range
    Dim ColCus As Long, ColPro As Long, ColCat As Long
    Set oTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    With oTab
        Set rngData = .DataBodyRange
        ColCus = .ListColumns("Customer Number").Index
        ColPro = .ListColumns("Provision").Index
        ColCat = .ListColumns("Category").Index
        ColCnt = .ListColumns.Count
    End With
    ' Load table into array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Set oDicBAD = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDicRR = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through table
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, ColCus)
        Select Case UCase(arrData(i, ColPro))
        Case "RR"
            If objDicRR.exists(sKey) Then
                Set objDicRR(sKey) = Application.Union(objDicRR(sKey), rngData.Rows(i))
            Else
                Set objDicRR(sKey) = rngData.Rows(i)
            End If
        Case "BAD"
            If Not oDicBAD.exists(sKey) Then
                oDicBAD(sKey) = ""
            End If
        End Select
    Next i
    ' Loop through cust.
    For Each sKey In oDicRR.Keys
        If Not oDicBAD.exists(sKey) Then
            If rngHL Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHL = oDicRR(sKey)
            Else
                Set rngHL = Application.Union(rngHL, oDicRR(sKey))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Highlight cust.
    rngData.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not rngHL Is Nothing Then
        rngHL.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 205, 5)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still do not highlight the right rows, i have added a snapshot of what the 2 dictionaries do and what is meant to be achieved.

Comment: Have you tested the code w/o change? I've uploaded the screenshot of my testing.

Comment: Thank you so much it's spot on and highlights the exact rows that need to be highlighted, but what have you changed in the code? I was studying your code and it wasn't highlighting the right rows, but it gets the right ones now.

Comment: The change is on `Set oDicRR(sKey) = rngData.Cells(i, ColCus).Resize(1, ColCnt)` because the ListObject may not start from cell A1.

Comment: The line could be simplified as `Set objDicRR(sKey) = rngData.Rows(i)`.